# Weird GIT Issue : push Failing with HTTP error 502

Tags: git, http, push

I have been running into a very strange issue with a git repo where I am able to edit and update an existing file (css, html, js, xml) and do a normal push BUT if I add new files to the repo or REPLACE existing files, I get the following error when I would usually input my credentials on a successful push:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 502
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have read over the many posts on this issue and have run:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

from the clone directory.

I am running: git version 1.8.3.2

```
$ git remote -v  outputs the following
origin http://[redacted]/git/TestProgram.git (fetch)
origin http://[redacted]/git/TestProgram.git (push)
```

On the server log, I see a Bad Gateway error but I KNOW that the git repo exists and is correct being that I'm able to clone it and update files - just not add or replace files in the clone.  I'm leaning towards this being a disk write permissions issue.  Has anyone run into anything similar - does this assessment sound valid?

Any ideas would be welcome, as I've been bashing my face off of this all week.

Answer (score 1):

Even before getting to the end of your post, I was thinking "Disk permission issues".  In fact I'm fairly certain that your error message is precisely the message I received when faced withthe same issue, although it's been a long time since I've used git over http.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, http is what I'm stuck with for right now. Were you able to get around the issue by updating disk permissions?  Rough situation because I don't have direct access to the server, I'm trying to prep as much info as possible for meeting with IT....

Comment: I wish I could help a little more.  In my case I had direct access to the server (in fact it was my responsibility that the permissions were wrong).  The problem isn't specifically related to using http, but of course the solution is a slightly different since with ssh you have to administer the individual users account permissions.  For http you have to assign permisssions correctly for whatever user the http daemon is acting through.  Probably the admin has to add the httpd's user to the git-users group.  I recommend giving the sysadmin a clear test for success.